# Building a loop that updates a column with the matching values?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to search a dataframe for certain keywords and then index the row entry where the keywords have been found for later operations.

Suppose I got a dataframe and some keywords which resemble the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"metals": ["copper", "zinc", "aluminium", "iron", "platinum", "gold", "silver", "copper and zinc"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

keywords = ["copper", "zinc"]
```

Ultimately, I would like to achieve something like:

```
# What I would like to obtain
[in] data
[out]
| ID | metals            | label          |
| -- | ----------------- | -------------- |
|0   |copper             | copper         |
|1   |zinc               | zinc           |
|2   |aluminium          | 0              |
|3   |iron               | 0              |
|4   |platinum           | 0              |
|5   |gold               | 0              |
|6   |silver             | 0              |
|7   |copper and zinc    | [copper, zinc] |
```

I came up with the subsequent loop, however it only returns:

```
df['label'] = 0

for word in keywords:
    df['label'][df['metals'].str.contains(word)] = word
    
# What I actually obtain
[in] data
[out]
| ID | metals            | label          |
| -- | ----------------- | -------------- |
|0   |copper             | copper         |
|1   |zinc               | zinc           |
|2   |aluminium          | 0              |
|3   |iron               | 0              |
|4   |platinum           | 0              |
|5   |gold               | 0              |
|6   |silver             | 0              |
|7   |copper and zinc    | zinc           |
```

How do I build a loop that updates the 'label' column with all the matching words in each row? I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to find all the occurrences of matching pattern:

```
pat = fr"\b({'|'.join(keywords)})\b"
df['label'] = df['metals'].str.findall(pat)

>>> df
            metals           label
0           copper        [copper]
1             zinc          [zinc]
2        aluminium              []
3             iron              []
4         platinum              []
5             gold              []
6           silver              []
7  copper and zinc  [copper, zinc]
```

In case you specifically want to have output in the desired format that you have shown in the question, you can additionally use `np.select`:

```
s = df['metals'].str.findall(fr"\b({'|'.join(keywords)})\b")
l = s.str.len()
df['label'] = np.select([l.ge(2), l.eq(1)], [s, s.str[0]], 0)


>>> df
            metals           label
0           copper          copper
1             zinc            zinc
2        aluminium               0
3             iron               0
4         platinum               0
5             gold               0
6           silver               0
7  copper and zinc  [copper, zinc]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.extractall`:

```
pattern = '|'.join(keywords)
df['label'] = (df['metals'].str.extractall(rf'\b({pattern})\b')[0]
                  .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
              )
```

Output:

```
            metals           label
0           copper        [copper]
1             zinc          [zinc]
2        aluminium             NaN
3             iron             NaN
4         platinum             NaN
5             gold             NaN
6           silver             NaN
7  copper and zinc  [copper, zinc]
```